# Comparing strings using strcmp in c

Tags: c, string, sockets, tcp, string.h

My goal is to get the server to print "it works" when "hello" is received from a client. The strcmp fuction is not working for me. I got told to use `f(strncasecmp(message,mess,5))` instead however it only prints it works when the client disconnects with "^c" using netcat. I have been trying to solve this for some time and haven't gotten anywhere. On client side i am just using netcat at the moment. Please go easy on down votes first time here tell me if you have an issue.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>  //strlen
#include<stdlib.h>  //strlen
#include<sys/socket.h>
#include<arpa/inet.h>   //inet_addr
#include<unistd.h>  //write

#include<pthread.h> //for threading , link with lpthread

void *connection_handler(void *);

int main(int argc , char *argv[])
{
    int socket_desc , new_socket , c , *new_sock;
    struct sockaddr_in server , client;
    char *message;

    //Create socket
    socket_desc = socket(AF_INET , SOCK_STREAM , 0);
    if (socket_desc == -1)
    {
        printf("Could not create socket");
    }

    //Prepare the sockaddr_in structure
    server.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    server.sin_port = htons( 9999 );

    //Bind
    if( bind(socket_desc,(struct sockaddr *)&server , sizeof(server)) < 0)
    {
        puts("bind failed");
        return 1;
    }
    puts("bind done");

    //Listen
    listen(socket_desc , 3);

    //Accept and incoming connection
    puts("Waiting for incoming connections...");
    c = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);
    while( (new_socket = accept(socket_desc, (struct sockaddr *)&client, (socklen_t*)&c)) )
    {
        puts("Connection accepted");

        //Reply to the client
        message = "Hello Client , I have received your connection. And now I will assign a handler for you\n";
        write(new_socket , message , strlen(message));

        pthread_t sniffer_thread;
        new_sock = malloc(1);
        *new_sock = new_socket;

        if( pthread_create( &sniffer_thread , NULL ,  connection_handler , (void*) new_sock) < 0)
        {
            perror("could not create thread");
            return 1;
        }

        //Now join the thread , so that we dont terminate before the thread
        //pthread_join( sniffer_thread , NULL);
        puts("Handler assigned");
    }

    if (new_socket<0)
    {
        perror("accept failed");
        return 1;
    }

    return 0;
}
/*
 * This will handle connection for each client
 * */
void *connection_handler(void *socket_desc)
{
    //Get the socket descriptor
    int sock = *(int*)socket_desc;
    int read_size;
    char *message , client_message[2000];
    //char *contents;
    //contents = "hello";
    //strcpy(mess,contents);
    //Send some messages to the client
    message = "Greetings! I am your connection handler\n";
    write(sock , message , strlen(message));

    message = "Now type something and i shall repeat what you type \n";
    write(sock , message , strlen(message));

    //Receive a message from client
    while( (read_size = recv(sock , client_message , 2000 , 0)) > 0 )
    {
        write(sock , client_message , strlen(client_message));
        char mess[] = "hello";
```

> Issue is here "if(strcmp(message, mess))"

```
        if(strcmp(message, mess)){
        printf("it works");
    }
    }
    if(read_size == 0)
    {
        puts("Client disconnected");
        fflush(stdout);
    }
    else if(read_size == -1)
    {
        perror("recv failed");
    }

    //Free the socket pointer
    free(socket_desc);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `strcmp` returns zero when the two strings are equal, so you probably want `if (strcmp(message, mess) == 0) ...` (`strcmp` is a three-way comparison function; it returns a negative value if `a` is lexically less then `b`, a positive value if `a` is lexically greater than `b` and zero on equality.)

Comment: in C, the stdout is buffer by the OS.  so text is not immediately passed to the terminal.  To force the text to be immediately passed to the terminal, either end the format string with a '\n' or call `fflush( stdout );`

Comment: this line: `while( (new_socket = accept(socket_desc, (struct sockaddr *)&client, (socklen_t*)&c)) )` is not correct.   `accept()` returns a -1 on error and this line will perform the enclosed code block under such conditions.  Suggest adding a comparison similar to: `>0`

Comment: regarding these two line: `new_sock = malloc(1);
        *new_sock = new_socket;`,  1) always check the returned value from malloc() to assure the operation was successful.  2) the variable `new_socket` is an `int` (depending on the underlying architecture and certain compiler options the size of a `int` is either 4 or 8 bytes.  Suggest: `if( NULL == (new_sock = malloc( sizeof( int )) ) { perror( "malloc failed" ); exit( EXIT_FAILURE ); } *new_sock = new_socket;`

Comment: this parameter of the call to `pthread_create()` `(void*) new_sock)` should be: `(void*) &new_sock)`

Comment: the function: `recv()` returns a `ssize_t` value, not an `int`, the variable: `read_size` should be declared as `ssize_t read_size;`

Comment: the posted code contains some 'magic' numbers, like 2000.  'magic' numbers make the code much more difficult to understand, debug, maintain.  Suggest using a #define to give each 'magic' number a meaningful name, then using that meaningful name throughout the code.

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding by us humans, 1) please consistently indent the code.  Indent after every opening brace '{'.  unindent before every closing brace '}'.  Never use tabs for indenting because every word processor/editor has the tab stops/tab width set differently. 2)  separate code blocks (for, if, else, while, do...while, switch, case, default) via a blank line.

Comment: Thanks for tips and taking the time to look through the code. Most people would not help out that much :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your condition, you check `if(strcmp(message, mess))`, which will be executed ***if `message` and `mess` are different***, as `strcmp` returns `0` only if the compared strings are equal. So, you need to change this line to:

```
if(strcmp(message, mess) == 0)
```

so that you execute the statements inside the `if` part if the strings are the same, as you want.

Comment: Ok thanks that works however it only prints it works when the connection is terminated at client end.

Comment: @Marievi "1 if they are different". That's not quite correct. `strcmp` is defined to return "an integer less than, equal to, or greater than zero if s1 (or the first n bytes thereof) is found, respectively, to be less than, to match, or be greater than s2".

Comment: @TimWilliams I am glad that I helped. If your problem is solved you could accept my answer. As for the second part of your comment, is that bothering you? Do you want the printing to be done before the client ends?

Comment: yes i would it would make my day if i could make it print it before client ends. If you could solve that it would be much appreciated.

Comment: @TimWilliams then you could probably ask another question with your new problem, showing your client code as well?

Comment: I'm wondering about the acceptance of this answer.  It does not answer the question, it just points out a logic problem in the code.  The root problem with the late text output is the format strings (to printf) are missing a trailing '\n'